# Jest Test - element.shadowRoot.querySelector() not retrieving element when given an id

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, dom, lwc-jest

I am attempting to retrieve and make assertions about certain elements using querySelector() with the respective id of that element. But, querySelector() isn't returning any elements with a given id.

For example, if I have the following markup:

```
    <template if:true={showPaginationButtons}>
                <div id="paginationButtonsDiv" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                        <template if:false={isFirstPageAccount}>
                            <lightning-button id="prev-account-page" onclick={handlePrevPageAccounts} label="Previous"></lightning-button>
                        </template>
                        <template if:false={isLastPageAccount}>
                            <lightning-button id="next-account-page" onclick={handleNextPageAccounts} label="Next"></lightning-button>
                        </template>
                </div>
 </template>
```

And in my Jest test I am attempting the following:

```
let div = accountDetails.shadowRoot.querySelector('#paginationButtonsDiv');
expect(div).not.toBe(null);
```

This is returning null each time.

To confirm the div is actually present, I have used `querySelectorAll('div')` and asserted that the list is of the correct size. This works.

I could use `querySelectorAll()` for these tests but I'd rather not. I won't go into detail as to why.

So, does `element.shadowRoot.querySelector(<id-of-element>`) not work with an id for some reason? Anything I find indicates that it should:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more an LWC thing than a Jest thing.  It isn't recommended to use `querySelector()` with the `id` attribute in LWC ([see docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work)), as the `id` "may be transformed into globally unique values when the template is rendered."

Instead, you can use the `data-id` attribute.  Per your example, the selector would look like this:

```js
let div = accountDetails.shadowRoot.querySelector('div[data-id=paginationButtonsDiv]');
```

See [HTML data-* global attribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)